# Removing focus from input box that was focussed earlier

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have one more input box - `ibox2`, on the same page.

Problem - After doing anything on `ibox1` and leaving value of length > 5 there, if I start typing in `ibox2` the focus jumps back to `ibox1`.

It is that `if` loop with `ibox1.focus()` that is doing it. How could I remove focus entirely from `ibox1` upon clicking outside and nullify the `if` loop and its statements.

I tried `blur`but it did not work.

```
var ibox1 = $("#inputbox1");

$(document).on("change", ibox1,function(e) { 

   var valu = ibox1.val();

   if(valu.length > 5){

      #do something  
      ibox1.focus(); #used this as input box lost focus with each charater typed.    

   }

});

var ibox2 = $("#inputbox2"); #This is for google places autocomplete.
```

PS - Please do not tag it as a duplicate one, I have tried almost everything here, and only then I posted this. I shall remove it upon getting solution.

Respected mods, I followed a nice accepted answer and made a mistake about understanding $('document'), but I now got it cleared. That's the reason I am not deleting this question, even though I said I would, as it might help others. You guys, if 
 you feel, could delete this. Thanks.

Comment: Please add *all* the relevant code and create a "snippet" right here in your question so that we can replicate your issue and provide better answers.

Comment: Can't see `ibox2` anywhere in the code.

Comment: I am still unable to reproduce it, can you please make a stackoverflow snippet or a jsfiddle?

Comment: Thanks for replying, Sirs. Code is too lengthy, involving many `script` sections. Hence, I kind of posted a pseudocode. It is a google place autocomplete coupled with easyautocomplete.Also, I am trying to avoid using `global` variables,at this moment, which might do the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The focus is jumping back to `ibox1` because you are instructing your document to do so each time the `onChange` event is fired.

e.g.: `$(document).on("change", ibox1, funct...` where you are calling for `ibox1.focus();` `.

Possible solution: bind your change event to the element of interest itself and avoid binding an event of such local significance to the whole document in the future.

Comment: I do understand what you are saying as it came to me too. But, I thought that, since, I have already passed on a selector `ibox1`,   the `input` event would be bound to `ibox1` only. Am I wrong, Sir?

Comment: yes sir., I think you are - Use `ibox1.on('change', function(e) {...` instead.

Comment: Thank you, Sir. Gladly accept that I was wrong. Followed what you said, used `ibox1`.bind("input", function()...)  instead of `$(document).bind...` and it worked great. Your words ` because you are instructing your document to do so` are now more clearer to me.

Answer (score 1):

Use a simple method to attach an event to inputs. Check below code it may help you.

```
(function(){
  var in1 = jQuery('#input1'); // first input
  var in2 = jQuery('#input2'); // second input

  // On change of first input
  in1.change(function(){
    if(this.val().length > 5){
      // do something
    }
  });

  // On change of second input
  in2.change(function(){
    if(this.val().length > 5){
      // do something
    }
  });

})();
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, Sir.  `selector.event` is the key as you & Mr. Bekim caught nicely. Upvoting your answer.